# How to change an email address to another directly inside a file?

Tags: sed, email

Say I have a PHP file with the following code line:

```
$to = "example-1_2@example-1_2.com";
```

I want to change only the email address between the two double quote marks to say `example@example.com`).

I have tried this which failed:

```
read new_email_address
sed -i 's/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$@^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$.^[a-z]*$/"${new_email_address}"/g' FILE
```

Comment: You don't say in which way it fails. Error message, no output, unexpected output... In any case, your regular expression matches a line that starts with a hex digit or dash or underscore, which doesn't match the PHP line, and the dollar in the replacement string would be used verbatim, as it is enclosed in single quotes. Thus, it doesn't work at several levels.

Comment: It's not quite certain what you want to achieve. You want to replace all email addresses in the code, or just example-1_2@example-1_2.com? Or something else?

Comment: @berndbausch by "hex digit" you mean to a letter or a number, right? About the replacement, I want to replace only the email address `example-1_2@example-1_2.com` in each occurrence (normally it would occur just once but I it might occur twice or more by some rare copying mistake).

Comment: Sorry for the "hex digit"; this is incorrect, and yes, letter-or-number would have been correct. I don't know what prevents you from simply replacing the email address itself? For example, `sed "s/example-1_2@example-1_2.com/${new_email_address}/"`?

Comment: @berndbausch I am creating an installation script to install a Content-Management-System-Updater (CMSU) which has to include an email and everything is so far automatic besides email setting; which I also want automatic.

Comment: If you want to replace a string that is (1) between two double-quotes and (2) has a single @ in the middle, this regular expression would match it: `"[a-zA-Z-_]*@[a-zA-Z-_]*"`. You may find better email-address-matchers on the internet. The problem is that you need to put the replacement string between double-quotes as well. There are several ways of handling this. Put backslashes before the double quotes, or compose the sed program in several steps. The former would look like `sed "s/\"[a-zA-Z-_]*@[a-zA-Z-_]*\"/\"${new_email}\"/"`.

Comment: @berndbausch thank you a lot ; if I understand the rules of this community correctly comments might get automatically deleted and such a detailed, beautiful example should not be deleted so please consider to publish it inside an answer.

Comment: Well thanks. I will add some explanation around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a brief comment about the updated `sed` command in your question, which currently reads

```bsh
sed -i 's/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$@^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$.^[a-z]*$/"${new_email_address}"/g' FILE
```

Notice that this contains two invalid character ranges (both read `0-9-_`) and that the variable `new_email_address` would not be expanded by the shell as it is in a single-quoted string.  I'm also not sure about what the intention is with `$@^` and `$.^`, as the `$` and `^` would be matching those characters literally at those positions in the expression.

---

Not seeing how the `$to` variable is used in the rest of the file, I'm going to assume that it's only assigned to in one single place, and that the line that you show occurs exactly like it does in the file.

```
sed 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' file >file.new
```

There is no point in trying to match an email address since we know already that the `$to` variable holds an email address.  The only thing we need to worry about is trying to find the correct line.  Matching email addresses with regular expressions is notoriously *difficult*.

A few things to note here:

- The `$` in `$to` does not need special handling as it's not occurring last in the expression.  If you use `-E` to enable extended regular expressions, then firstly, don't, and secondly, escape the `$` in `$to` as `\$` in the pattern.
- The string `$to` will *not* be seen as a shell variable as it's within single quotes.
- `$new_email_address` *is* a shell variable, so we're temporarily breaking out of the single quotes to introduce the value of that variable, double quoted.

I would suggest not using `-i` here, as you don't yet know whether the substitution does the right thing or whether it messes up the file.  It's better to write the result to a fresh filename instead.

Also, with `-ir`, you are instructing `sed` to use `r` as the backup file suffix.  I assume that you wanted to use the option `-r` (or `-E`, which would be more commonly supported).  However, neither `-r` nor `-E` is needed as we're not using any extended regular expressions for this simple substitution.

Testing the above command:

```
$ cat file
$to = "example-1_2@example-1_2.com";
```

```
$ new_email_address=myself@my.host.here.net
$ sed 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' file >file.new
```

```
$ cat file.new
$to = "myself@my.host.here.net";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120957/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-how-to-change-an-email-address-to-another-di).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace a string that is (1) between two double-quotes and (2) has a single @ in the middle, this regular expression would match it:

```
"[a-zA-Z_.-]*@[a-zA-Z_.-]*"
```

Note that the dash has to be at the end in each character class, and I added a dot before and after the @.

Theoretically, other characters are possible, such as %. With a little research, you may find regular expressions that match email addresses better than that, but let's assume your email addresses conform to this expression.

The problem is the replacement string in your `sed` program. You need to put it between double-quotes, since it contains a shell variable, and the regular expression also contains double-quotes.

The easiest way of handling this, in my opinion, is by putting backslashes before the double quotes. For example

```
sed "s/\"[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*\"/\"${new_email}\"/"
```