# How to replace an email in a (PHP) file from the command line without sed?

Tags: bash, text-processing, awk, sed, user-interface

I have a PHP file which contains an email address as with `$to = "example-1_2@example-1_2.com";` and I want to replace the email address to another directly from the terminal.

The following code based on [another similar code by Kuslanada](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639048/460541) worked:

```
read new_email_address
sed -i 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' FILE
```

Kuslananda told me in comments (paraphrasing):

- My expression is **the concatenation of** a single-quoted string, a double-quoted string (the variable), and then another short single-quoted string

---

As a non professional sysadmin I might use `sed` once in two years and I find its syntax somewhat difficult to remember and confusing for someone like me which doesn't work with it on a regular basis (the quoting rules clued by Kuslananda there are a bit confusing for me, let along when entire `sed` commands are normally single-quoted by themselves).
Perhaps there is a way to make Kusalananda's command more "intuitive" or "accessible" for some others and myself. Maybe some backslashes to break the command to pieces would help or maybe another utility would be better for me to do such text replacement.

---

How to replace an email in a (PHP) file from the command line **without** `sed`?

Comment: Your regular expression makes no sense. You have multiple `$` in there, what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: @terdon I thought that the `*$` means anything that ends with [CHARACTERS]. Of course I was wrong. I think I should delete this code; I saw you answered about `sed` but I need a way to do essentially what Kusalananda did but without sed because the syntax of `sed` is just to hard to me to remember as someone who doesn't use `sed` frequently (rather, once in a few years).

Comment: @terdon The first one (now deleted) does not makes sense (as it tries to match literal `^` and `$` in non-obvious places), the second one is mine. `$` matches a `$` in a BRE, unless it's the last character in an expression or a sub-expression, in which case it matches the end of the line.

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah, but that still doesn't make sense since there are no `$` in the line after the first character (note that I was referring to the first version of the post).

Comment: @timesharer your problem isn't related to sed. You will have the same issue no matter what tool you have if you try to combine a shell variable with the tool's syntax. The only way around it would be to use something that can take a variable as an argument (perl or awk etc) but that would include learning another whole new syntax and logic. The general syntax for sed replacement is very simple: `sed 's/old/new/'`. It is only complicated because you want to use a shell variable.

Comment: The thing that would make it easier would be to open the file in an interactive text editor, and then change the value by hand.

Comment: Or use `grep -o` to see if there is more then this one email address in the file tree. Because if there isn't, the whole original requirement becomes moot

Comment: I thank you terdon and Kuslananda to point out that the "problem" is not the nature of `sed` but rather the fact that I try to expand a variable inside `sed`... Well, if AWK and Perl aren't simpler for that (possibly evident about AWK by *guest_7*'s answer) I wonder about @roaima's way with `grep -o` because I do prefer some automation over direct changing with a text editor, in this case. roaima, please consider to help some others and myself by publishing a short answer.

Comment: `grep` is a tool for finding and printing strings that match an expression, not for editing text, so you can't write a grep command to modify text, just to find text and print it. The standard Unix tools for editing text are `ed`, `grep`, and `sed` and the sed solution you have (`s/regexp/string/`) is as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **awk** utility which looks at lines in terms of fields separated by delimiters you set on the command line with the -F option.

```
read new_email_address
awk -F '"' -v new="$new_email_address" '
  $1 == "$to = " {$2 = new}
1' OFS='"' your_phpfile
```

---

```
awk -v q=\" -v new="$new_email_address" '
BEGIN {
  new_esc = new
  gsub(/[&]/, "\\\\&", new_esc)
  repl = q new_esc q";"
}
sub(\
    /\$to = ".*";$/, \
     "$to = " repl   \
)+1' your_phpfile
```

Comment: I thank you for coming to my aid; this looks to me simpler than another similar answer you wrote in another question of mine (which I also venerate): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639222/how-to-break-sed-commands-to-nested-parts-in-a-bash-environment/639286#639286

Comment: Is there any chance to further simplify the `awk` command (especially by mean of nesting) so to make it look even more similar to [my nested pseudocode here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/639222/how-to-break-sed-commands-to-nested-parts-in-a-bash-environment)? Sorry if the question is troublesome, I just never ran any `awk` command before in my life.

Comment: @timesharer I recommend that you take the time to go through my other answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639244 which deals with separating out the quotes used in search n replace operations. This thereby solves your problem of having to deal with weaving in n out of single n double quotes.Let me know if some clarifications are needed.I , in fact, considered those to be the most natural fit for your particular requirement at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Quoted shell variables will only be expanded if their outer level of quoting is a double quote. To illustrate:

```
$ var=foo
$ echo '"$var"'
"$var"
$ echo "'$var'"
'foo'
```

So, variables are only expanded if the *outer* level of quotes around them is double.

The next problem is that your regular expression is wrong. `$` in a regular expression means "the end of the line", so you can't have multiple `$` in there like that. I don't really understand what you are trying to do with that regular expression, so I will just assume you want to change the email address found after the string `$to =`. If so, try this:

```
sed -i "s/\\$to = \"[^\"]*\"/\\$to = $new_email_address/" FILE
```

I have to escape the `"` (`\"`) and `$` (`\$to`) to avoid the `$to` to be read as a variable and so the inner `"` don't close the opening `"`. I also have to add another layer of escape (`\\$`) so that the `$` isn't seen by the shell and is instead passed to sed. And yes, I realize this is ridiculously complicated.

Alternatively, you can separate it into multiple single and double quoted expressions as I think you were trying to do:

```
sed 's/\$to = "[^"]*"/$to = '"$new_email_address"'/' FILE
```

Comment: The quoted code from my answer is what they says it is: `'s/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'`, `"$new_email_address"`, and `'";/'`.

Comment: @Kusalananda you're quite right, my bad. I didn't parse it properly. I always avoid this syntax actually for precisely that reason: I always have trouble parsing it by eye.

Comment: The thing that makes it slightly harder to parse is that there should be a set of double quotes around the variable's value in the replacement string too, so that you get `$to = "whatever";` as the result, not `$to = whatever`.