# How to break sed commands to nested parts in a Bash environment?

Tags: sed, newlines

I work with a CentOS Bash environment and I have this long one liner `sed` command which I, as someone who is not a professional sysadmin and works with `sed` perhaps once in two years, find a bit "confusing", at least as a long one liner:

```
read new_email_address
sed -i 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' FILE
```

I want to break the `sed` command to something like the following nested pseudocode:

```
sed -i
    '
        s/
            $to = ".*";$
        /
            $to = "'"$new_email_address"'";
        /g
    '
FILE_PATH
```

Comment: It may be possible to build up a bash variable (say SED_COMMAND) by a "here document" assignment so as to make the steps clear. The call to sed will then be `sed -i ${SED_COMMAND} FILE`.

Comment: Hello @Kapil ; at least in my mind, none of the current 5 answers match what I ought to do in the pseudocode ; an answer with an heredocument was yet to have been published; it might be the closest case my pseudocode, in great plea share an answer about this in your free time; thanks anyway,

Comment: The [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639226/316998) given by @muru is roughly what I had in mind except that one can use a here-document instead of `printf`.

Comment: @Kapil I understand, thanks ; sadly, it's still hard for me to read...

Answer (score 4):

I'd use `perl` here. `-i` is a non-standard option that some `sed` implementations have copied from `perl` but it not portable. Using `sed` that way is also a command injection vulnerability as the contents of `$new_email_address` ends up being interpreted as `sed` code (and there are commands in the GNU `sed` language that can run arbitrary commands, try for instance entering `/;ereboot;#` at that `read` prompt).

```
IFS= read -r new_email_address

REPLACEMENT="$new_email_address" perl -pi -e '
  s{
     (\$to \s* = \s* ") .* (" \s* ; \s* )$
   }{$1$ENV{REPLACEMENT}$2}gx
 ' FILE
```

In `perl`

- you can use `s{...}{...}flags` in addition of `s/.../.../flags` which makes it easier to see matching pairs (and allows `{`, `}` inside as long as they're matched).
- with the `x` flag, you can add spacing (and even comments) inside the regexp to make it easier to read (note that those spaces are not part of the regexp, it's the `\s*` that matches any amount of whitespace).
- you can safely use any arbitrary string in the replacement, even those containing `&`, `/`, backslash or newline by passing it via an environment variable for instance.
- as long as you don't use `-C`/`-Mlocale`/`-Mopen=locale`... options, `perl` works at byte level so its `.*` will never fail to match, even if the input doesn't form valid text in the locale.
- contrary to some `sed` implementations, `perl` has no limit on line length (other than available memory) and won't choke on input containing NUL bytes or not ending in a newline character.

To allow whitespace in the replacement part as well, you can add the `e` flag which causes the replacement to be `perl` code:

```
REPLACEMENT="$new_email_address" perl -pi -e '
  s{
     (\$to \s* = \s* ") .* (" \s* ; \s* )$
   }{
     $1 . $ENV{REPLACEMENT} . $2
   }gxe
 ' FILE
```

For instance.
Also remember that using `read` without setting `$IFS` and without `-r` rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will be more readable to you, but you could build the `sed` expression first using `printf` and then use it with `sed`:

```bsh
sed_expr=$(printf 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "%s";/' "$new_email_address")
sed -i "$sed_expr" FILE
```

This way, IMO, it's easier to see what sed is going to do in its entirety, and also what role exactly the input will play in it.

Comment: `printf -v sed_expr '...' "..."` in `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to keep the quotes separate is to break the sed command by taking help of multiple -e sed codelettes for search n replace separated.

```
q=\"; # a double quote character
sed -i \
    -e '/$to = ".*";$/c\'  \
    -e "\$to = $q$new_email_address$q;" \
FILE
```

---

```
sed -i \
    -e '/$to = ".*";$/!b' \
    -e "s//\$to = $q$new_email_address$q;/" \
FILE;
```

Comment: About the first example: Perhaps there is better variable name than `q`, something more meaningful/readable (I don't know what `q` means there).

Comment: About the second example: Is `!b` some type of regex? | Also, I wonder why there are two forward slashes there (as with `"s//`) | Also, I read a (non defined?) defined `q` variable expansion inside and wonder why is it there.

Comment: The variable `q` holds a quote `"` . It's not strictly necessary, we can use an escaped quote as well `\"` .I used it to minimuze the quotes since you had stated a difficulty in keeping track of these in more quantity.

Comment: guest_7 thanks ! I do indeed have hard time working so much quoting at least in the current version of `sed` and without nesting as in my pseudocode ; the idea of such a variable is nice (with some notes ; I think I would try that).

Comment: `!b` is not a regex, rather the inversion of the status of a regex and print the line. So, print all lines matching the criteria AND go get the next line. The `//` is a `sed` artefact standing in for the last regex used.So in this case the previous line's regex.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted command is something similar to what [I wrote in a recent answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639048/116858) (with `-i` added):

```
sed 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' file
```

This is invoking `sed` with a single editing command. The command used in the `sed` expression is the `s` command, which does a substitution, i.e. it replaces something that matches a regular expression with something else.

The general form of the `s` command is `range s/pattern/replacement/flags`.  In the command that we're dealing with here, there is no `range` expression (the `s` command is applied to *all* lines in the input text), and there are no `flags`.  We therefore have a `sed` editing script on the general form

```
s/pattern/replacement/
```

As you can see in the command, the `pattern` bit is

```
$to = ".*";$
```

This pattern matches the literal text `$to = "` followed by *anything* (any length of sequence of any character), followed by the literal text `";`.  The `$` at the end forces that last `";` bit to match at the very end of the line.

Then we have the `replacement` bit.

Since you want to replace with something that depends on the value of a shell variable, we must temporarily break out of the single-quoted string which is the `sed` expression.  We do this just after

```
$to = "
```

in the replacement.  The value of the shell variable `new_email_address` is inserted, properly quoted with double quotes so that the shell does not split it on spaces or perform filename globbing on its value.

Once the value has been inserted, we end the `replacement` part of the `s` command with

```
";
```

and that's the full `replacement` field, `$to = "` followed by some value (the new email address), and then `";`.

So, to break it apart and make it obvious what each bit of this command does and is:

Structure of the `sed` command:

```
    sed 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' file
         s/  pattern   /          replacement          /
```

Bits of strings making up the `sed` expression in the shell:

```
    sed 's/$to = ".*";$/$to = "'"$new_email_address"'";/' file
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^
         single-quoted string    double-quoted       final single-quoted bit
                                 string for shell
                                 variable expansion
```

The above in a more schematic way

```
    sed 'something here'"$variable_value_here"'ending here' file
```

The `something here` bit happens to end with a double quote, and the `ending here` bit happens to start with a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way can be:

- First make the email address safe for plugging in on the RHS of a sed s/// command.
- Then write up a multiline, whitespace sprinkled, sed code in terms of printf format.
- Finally, bring together the sed code and strip off all whitespace from it and feed it to sed option -f .

```
email_rhs=$(printf '%s\n' "$new_email_address" | sed -e 's:[\&/]:\\&:g;$!s:$:\\:')

sed -i -Ef - <<_CODE_ FILE_PATH
$(printf -v fmt \
  '
    s/
      (\$to \s* = \s*) ".*" ;$
     /
      \\\\1 "%%s" ;
    /g
  '
printf "${fmt//[$IFS]/}" "$email_rhs")
_CODE_
```